# django memcached and ajax requests

Tags: ajax, django, memcached

I have setup memcached (unix socket) for my django application. However it seems that some ajax requests do not work, as expected, while memcached is on. I am using memcached on my entire site.

For example in this javascript function the `.load()` directive works the first time, but after that it keeps 'fetching' the same page from cache.

```
function placeBet(user, bet) {
    var ajax_data = {
        status:false,
        message: ''
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:'/place_bet/' + user + '/?ajax=&bet=' + bet,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:ajax_data,
        success:function (data){
            var message = "";
            $('#user_open_bets').load('/ob/' + user + '/?ajax=');
            if (data.status == false){
                alert(data.message);
            }
        } // success
    }); // ajax
}
```

How can I force those ajax request to reload from database instead from cache?

EDIT.

This is my `settings.py` MIDDLEWARE classes

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'main.common.tz_middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
     'main.common.sslMiddleware.SSLRedirect',
     'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
```

Comment: I am using memcached too.I can't find any problems specific to ajax requests.Is it specific to some browsers?

Comment: No. It happens with every browser. Even in different computers. I paste my `settings.py` `MIDDLEWARE` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer was simpler than I thought. I found the solution in the django docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers

I copy paste (for other people to know)

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
    # ...
```

Having said that, @Alex's suggestion seems interesting and I would like to try it. However now my server is down for migration reasons. I need to wait for some hours. I will report here, later.

Answer (score 1):

This is default browser behaviour (caching ajax requests). To avoid that pass addictional parameter to your request:

```
url:'/place_bet/' + user + '/?ajax=&bet=' + bet+'&t='+new Date().getTime()
```

EDIT:
correct url to load is:

```
'/ob/' + user + '/?ajax=&t=' + new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: No, it's a POST. Browsers don't cache POSTs.

Comment: I believe this is the correct idea but on the wrong line. `$('#user_open_bets').load('/ob/' + user + '/?ajax=');` does the GET which is likely being cached.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding param

```
cache: false,
```

to your ajax request? Forexample:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/place_bet/' + user + '/?ajax=&bet=' + bet,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:ajax_data,
    cache: false,
    success:function (data){
        var message = "";
        $('#user_open_bets').load('/ob/' + user + '/?ajax=');
        if (data.status == false){
            alert(data.message);
        }
    } // success
});
```